# If I buy a song on Bandcamp, can I then use that song in my audio streaming website project accessible by the public?

Tags: copyright, internet, music

I want to replicate this site here (note I am not a non-profit like freeCodeCamp):

https://coderadio.freecodecamp.org/

I'd like to repurpose it to feature a different genre of music. To accomplish this, I must build a new playlist. Since my site will be accessible to the public, I'd like to use songs that will not violate copyright.

From my basic understanding, Bandcamp music is DRM-free when purchased. I'm vaguely familiar with what DRM is, but unsure if that qualifies me to use the purchased songs in my new project or not.

https://get.bandcamp.help/hc/en-us/articles/360013673153-Are-Bandcamp-s-download-formats-DRM-free-

https://bandcamp.com/#discover

If Bandcamp is a no-go, are there alternative music platforms that you could recommend?

Answer (score 4):

DRM-free is not license free. DRM is just an attempt to enforce copyright licenses via software. DRM will theoretically prevent you from playing the music unless you have a license that allows you to play it. The lack of DRM it doesn't mean you can do whatever you want with the recording. It just means that any violation of copyright rules will have to be settled using the legal system. If the copyright holder finds you offering their music for replay without a license to do so, they can take you to court to make you stop.

Bandcamp and other distributors have negotiated a contract with the musical artists and other copyright holders to offer their music for replay on their site. If you want to legally offer music to which you don't hold the copyright for replay on your site, you too will have to negotiate a license with the copyright holders.